# Visual Studio Code: Modified settings not applying

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I am trying to change a setting in VSC and it doesn't seem to be applying.

I'm doing this from the settings menu and not the JSON file but it should still work.  It also has a yellow line beside the modified setting instead of a blue one, which leads me to believe that I have to apply it somehow but can't see how.  I've also tried opening and closing VSC to see if it reset with new setting but it did not.

How do I make this work?

EDIT: My post was closed because apparently somebody thinks it was answered [elsewhere](/q/19124601).  The post it redirected me to has nothing to do with what I am inquiring about.  I'm not dealing with the output cells of a dataframe;  I am talking about the output of statistics of the data.

[setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQQGc.png)
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUZa2.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are some settings in VS Code (including those contributed by non-built-in extensions) that require refreshing something after changing the setting. For example, I vaguely recall there being some TypeScript settings or tsconfig things. In general, this happens when whatever code that defines the behaviour that depends on that setting wasn't written to detect the setting change. Sometimes that code is the code of VS Code itself, or of an extension.

You can reload VS Code using the `Developer: Reload Window` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). Also check if any related extensions have a reload/refresh command. Ex. TypeScript's `TypeScript: Reload Project` and `TypeScript: Restart TS Server`. For UI things (like a Notebook editor tab), you could try to just close and reopen that part of the UI.

For other more general problems, you might just be doing something wrong, or there could be a bug, or something at a different configuration [scope](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) could be taking precedence.

Comment: Unfortunately none of that worked.  Is there an apply button for the settings somewhere that I am not seeing?  I also tried increasing the text line limit (as an alternative) and still no change.   I added an image in OP of the output that I need expanded for context.

Comment: Actually I'm starting to think that this setting applies to dataframe outputs (cells).  I am trying to expand metric feedback (dtype readout for 100+ attributes).